# Form field with id|name|label|value "filter" not found in behat/minkcontext

Tags: php, behat, mink

This is my scenario:

```
Scenario: Search for class name that consist "dance"
Given I am on "/classes"
When I select "Class Name" from "filter"
And I fill in "dance" at "search"
When I press "Search"
```

This is the page's html:

```
<div class="row" style="margin:0;">
    <div class="2u 12u$(medium)" style="padding-left:0;">

        <form method="POST" action="{{ URL::to('/') }}/classes">
            <div class="12u$">
                <div class="select-wrapper form-group" style="width:150px;">
                    <select name="filter" id="filter">
                        <option value="keywords">- Filter by -</option>
                        <option value="keywords">All</option>
                        <option value="benefits">Benefits</option>
                        <option value="classname">Class name</option>
                        <option value="description">Description</option>
                        <option value="start date">Start Date</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <form method="POST" action="{{ URL::to('/') }}/classes">
        <div class="form-group" style="padding-left:0;">
            <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Search" id="search" name="search" style="height: 42px; width: 300px;"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        </div>
```

When I run the test case using behat features/view.feature
I get the error:

```
When I select "Class Name" from "filter"
 Form field with id|name|label|value "filter" not found.
```

How can I resolve this error???

Comment: Make sure the page is loaded and check if the element is inside an iframe, if yes then switch to the iframe.

Comment: @lauda the page is loaded and the element is not inside an iframe. I still get the same error